# Is it possible to show a image/message in spotfire text area to wait for data to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, c#, r, ironpython, spotfire

I built a spotfire report in which i am retrieving data from web by running iron python script on a button click .But the problem here is after clicking the button the script is running at the back and it may take few seconds to populate the data in report actually the user will have no idea whether the data loading is going or its done . so any way that we can show Image or a Message signing the data loading or done.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While I believe it might be difficult (but not impossible) to report progress on the ongoing task, would it be enough for you to set a string document property at the end of your ironpython script to for instance: "Data loaded"?

To set a document property from ironpython, use:

```
Document.Properties["propertyName"] = "Data loaded"
```

Then add a property control to a text area and have it show the value of the document property. Once the script completes the text will then be shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks Chris , we have two input property controls where we will provide the start and end date and then we have to click on a button to capture the dates provided and then script has to be executed and populate the data in report . please suggest me where i need to include this property control

Comment: @Rama: You can put it anywhere. If it works with your layout, maybe you can put it next to your button that triggers the script?

In the text area, just do Insert property control -> Label and select the property that your script is writing to.